# Hahn Banach theorem for distance

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

How can I prove that $d = dist(z,L) = \sup_{f \in C[0,1]*} f(z)$. So far I constructed extension $ f$ in $ L_1 = span\{z, L\}$ where $ L = \{ x \in C[0,1]: x(0) = 0 \} $ and $ z(t) = e^t$. I got $f(y+\alpha*z) = \alpha d$ but I do not know how to prove the distance equation.

Any help would be appreaciated!

P.S. I'm not 100% sure that my solution is correct.

Comment: Are you sure that $\mathrm{dist}(z, L) = \displaystyle \sup_{f \in C[0, 1]^*} f(z)$ is true? Because if $z \neq 0$, clearly $\displaystyle \sup_{f \in C[0, 1]^*} f(z) = \infty$ must be true. You have to impose a bound on $\lVert f \rVert$.

Comment: @Meowdog yes, I forgot to mention, $ \| f \| = 1 $

Comment: The extension to $L_1$ is a good start. Prove that $f$ is continuous with $\lVert f \rVert = 1$. Then take a Hahn-Banach extension $g \in C[0, 1]^*$. We have $\lVert g \rVert = 1$, $g(z) = d$ and $g \vert_L = 0$. Therefore $\displaystyle d \leq \sup_{f \in C[0, 1]^*, ~ \lVert f \rVert = 1} f(z)$. The other direction I am not yet sure about...

Comment: @Meowdog Thank you so much!